# Erlide immediately hangs

Tags: erlang

Erlide with OS X Mavericks and Eclipse (Kepler) 4.3.1 immediately hangs when either trying to create a new Erlang project or attempting to look at Preferences > Erlang.

Is there a fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to reinstall? Perhaps also using the beta version or bleeding edge version should give you important fixes.

http://erlide.org/installation/

Comment: I did re-install several times and I'm using the nightly build which should be the most recent.